# Dynamically resizeable video in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

### The Problem

I'm making a list of videos using `RecyclerView` and `ExoPlayer` and it works as expected. However, I have some situations when I need to display videos with different aspect ratios, I need some how to know the aspect ratio of the video before downloading the full video and then resize the exoplayer in the recyclerview based on that ratio.

### My Question is

How to know the width and height (or aspect ratio) of the video in `ExoPlayer` before downloading the video content (maybe after loading some meta data of the video).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to get meta data before downloading. I'm currently working on the same project and what i did is store the meta data of each video on the database manually and receive them along with the video.